# How can I communicate a Raspberry pi to a PLC? I keep getting errors, any help would be appreciated

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ipython, serial-communication, plc

I'm new to the raspberry pi and PLC world, like I know very very little. However, I'm trying to have USB communication between the raspberry pi and PLC.
The PLC I'm using is a VersaMax (IC200NDR010-FJ), which only has one ej45 port so I'm using a USB to ej45 converter for communication. Below is the code I have found online that looked really straightforward. However, as I attempt to run the program, I get " ValueError: Not a valid parity: '0'." This was my attempt #1.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ipython
SudoPython 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient

In [2]: client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu' ,port=' /dev/ttyUSB0' ,baudrate
   ...: =9600, parity='0')

In [3]: client.read_coils(2048,1,unit=1).bits
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ecf7c3f6dc42> in <module>()
----> 1 client.read_coils(2048,1,unit=1).bits

/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/client/common.pyc in read_coils(self, address, count, **kwargs)
     46         '''
     47         request = ReadCoilsRequest(address, count, **kwargs)
---> 48         return self.execute(request)
     49 
     50     def read_discrete_inputs(self, address, count=1, **kwargs):

/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.pyc in execute(self, request)
    104         :returns: The result of the request execution
    105         """
--> 106         if not self.connect():
    107             raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.__str__()))
    108         return self.transaction.execute(request)

/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.pyc in connect(self)
    595                                         stopbits=self.stopbits,
    596                                         baudrate=self.baudrate,
--> 597                                         parity=self.parity)
    598             if self.method == "rtu":
    599                 if self._strict:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.pyc in __init__(self, port, baudrate, bytesize, parity, stopbits, timeout, xonxoff, rtscts, write_timeout, dsrdtr, inter_byte_timeout, exclusive, **kwargs)
    219         self.baudrate = baudrate
    220         self.bytesize = bytesize
--> 221         self.parity = parity
    222         self.stopbits = stopbits
    223         self.timeout = timeout

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.pyc in parity(self, parity)
    330         """Change parity setting."""
    331         if parity not in self.PARITIES:
--> 332             raise ValueError("Not a valid parity: {!r}".format(parity))
    333         self._parity = parity
    334         if self.is_open:

ValueError: Not a valid parity: '0'

In [4]:
```

Attempt #2
I tried submiting the commands one at a time to hopefully fix the invalid parity but I ended up receiving a different error of "TypeError: unbound method read_coils() must be called with ModbusSerialClient instance as first argument (got int instance instead)."

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ipython 
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient

In [2]: client = ModbusSerialClient

In [3]: method='rtu'

In [4]: port=' /dev/ttyUSB0'

In [5]: baudrate=9600

In [6]: parity='0'

In [7]: client.read_coils(2048,1,unit=1).bits
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ecf7c3f6dc42> in <module>()
----> 1 client.read_coils(2048,1,unit=1).bits

TypeError: unbound method read_coils() must be called with ModbusSerialClient instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

In [8]:
```

Any guidance on this task would be thoroughly appreciated! I'm trying to learn this on a steep curve.

Thank you!

Comment: `client = ModbusSerialClient` just makes `client` another name for the class.  You have to actually call it, with appropriate parameters, to get an instance you can do things like `.read_coils()` with.  I suspect the original problem is that the `parity` parameter needed to be an integer, not a string.

Comment: How do I change the parity parameter to an integer not a string? I'm unsure how to approach the invalid parity value issue.

Comment: `parity=0` instead of `parity='0'`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot after work. I'll report back results.

Comment: Hello, I have gone ahead and modified the code to say parity =0 but I'm still receiving the same "Not a valid parity: 0" error but now it doesn't contain the '0'. Do I have to set other parameters that I forgot?

Comment: I took a look at the pymodbus documentation, and apparently it wants one of ‘N’, ‘E’, ‘O’, ‘M’, or ‘S’ for the `parity=` option.  I had interpreted your attempt as wanting to use the number zero, but maybe you had intended to use the letter 'O'?

Comment: Hello Jason, you are correct, once I changed the zero I had used to E (I assume that is even), the parity error went away. However, now I'm having connectivity issues. I changed the E to an O just to see what would happen and I received the same connection error.

Comment: ```/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.pyc in execute(self, request)
    105         """
    106         if not self.connect():
--> 107             raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.__str__()))
    108         return self.transaction.execute(request)
    109 

ConnectionException: Modbus Error: [Connection] Failed to connect[ModbusSerialClient(rtu baud[9600])]

In [4]: 
```

Comment: This is the video I'm following, if it helps. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRpWjjRNE-c

Comment: I'm currently using a ej45 to usb converter. I do plan to use a ttl converter for tx and rx communications through the gpio pins but I want to get it working through the usb port first.